# Tutorial to set up wordpress iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, wordpress, xml-rpc

I'm starting to create a new iOS app, which pull and push data from Wordpress.

but i do not know how to start, i know of XMLRPC. will appreciate if anyone can point to me any web tutorial or sample code.

i will like to read wordpress post as CMS, convert to iPhone readable XML format passing value to the app. also to write to wordpress.

des

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the following urls. it will be of help you.

http://ios.wordpress.org/development/

https://github.com/eczarny/xmlrpc

Answer (score 1):

There is an iOS app from [Wordpress](http://ios.wordpress.org/) which makes blogging easier from iOS devices.

If you can explain more about what you are upto, maybe I can help more...

Comment: Thanks Srikar, updated my post.
in short, i wanna use wordpress as CMS, read as XML and write to wordpress